# How to learn the language for a stay in Ukraine?

Tags: ukraine, languages

I am considering to live in Kyiv for a couple of months. I visited the city last summer and it pleasantly surprised me. I would like to learn the local language to make my way around easier. Any suggestions?

Comment: Related: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/37574/which-languages-to-brush-up-on-for-ukraine-trip

Answer (score 4):

Couple of links for you:

1. [Centre for Language Development](http://ruslang.kiev.ua/o-kompanii.html) ([FB](https://www.facebook.com/langdevelop/)). They teach Russian and Ukrainian.
2. [ECHO Eastern Europe](https://echoee.com/). The same thing, this center seems to be more certified, but more expensive too.
3. [Free Ukrainian courses](http://movaua.org.ua/). It is a public volunteer initiative, aimed at saving and enriching Ukrainian cultural heritage.
   But the enrollment seems to be over (ended at Sept 29th) and some Ukrainian proficiency level required (applicants are taking tests).